# How to solve #N/A value using Google Sheet =importxml function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet that want to import value value of Google search result using importxml function. Sometimes I get #N/A in cell A2.

I used while loop to keep trying to fetch the data and still I don't get data even if I wait for long time. Is it possible to setup a JavaScript timer so runs until I get value in cell A2 then timer stops and allow the rest of code to continue?

What should I do in order to avoid such cases and always get value on cell A2? Any Alternative solution?

```
  var queryString = Math.random();

  var cellFunction1 = '=IMPORTXML("' + SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C2').getValue() + '&randomNumber=' + queryString + '","'+ SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D2').getValue() + '")';
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A2').setValue(cellFunction1);

  var stop = 0;
  while (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A2').getValue() === "#N/A" && stop++<10) {
            Utilities.sleep(5000);
            var queryString3 = Math.random();
          var cellFunction1 = '=IMPORTXML("' + SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C2').getValue() + '&randomNumber=' + queryString3 + '","'+ SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D2').getValue() + '")';
          SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A2').setValue(cellFunction1);
      }
```

Comment: What do you have in C2 and D2?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. I suspect it's because the code tries to .getValue from the cells before the cells' values are updated from IMPORTXML.

My workaround was to write two separate functions, one to force the IMPORTXML to refresh, and then the other to write the data into the sheet. Then I gave the IMPORTXML a trigger to run every 5 minutes, and then the write function with its own trigger.

You might want to try this:

```
function refresher() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetById("input");
  // Cell input!A2 holds the formula '=IMPORTXML(A1, XMLpath)'
  //So now we give input!A1 a URL with a random ?number behind...
  //...to force IMPORTXML to refresh
  sheet.getRange(1, 1)
    .setValue("http://www.urlWhereInfoResides.com/?" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 40));
}
```

^ Give refresher() a trigger to run every 5 minutes

```
function writer() {
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  //assumes desired value sits in cell input!A2
  var input = ss2.getSheetById("input")
    .getRange(2, 1)
    .getValue();
  //adds input value into a new row in output sheet
  var outputSheet = ss2.getSheetById("output");
  var output = outputSheet.getRange(outputSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1)
    .setValue(input);
}
```

^ Give writer() a trigger to run every 5 minutes or whatever is needed